# How to write an array in Alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js

I have the following code which should loop over an array to populate an HTML select element but getting zero data?

```
<div class="w-full" x-data="{classes: [
                            {
                            room: 'online',
                            id: 1,
                            },
                            {
                            room: 'in class',
                            id: 2,
                            }
                            ]}">
  <select name="" id="">
    <template x-for="class in classes" :key="class.id">
    <option x-text="class.room" :value="class.room"></option>
      </template>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this. I renamed `class` to `cls` (may be `class` word is conflicting though did not see any error in concole)

https://codepen.io/rajdeepdebnath/pen/MWyNoKj?editors=1010

```
<div class="w-full" x-data="{classes: [
                            {
                            room: 'online',
                            id: 1,
                            },
                            {
                            room: 'in class',
                            id: 2,
                            }
                            ]}">
  <select name="" id="">
    <template x-for="cls in classes" :key="cls.id">
    <option x-text="cls.room" :value="cls.room"></option>
      </template>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make the Codepen Rajdeep. Yes I could not see any errors either